# When app is launched due to intent filter is onCreate() still called?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on an android app. I registered an intent filter. Do I have to duplicate the initial setup code from onCreate() into the onResume() function? or will onCreate() be called before going into onResume()?

Thanks

EDIT: lol, don't know how i didn't think of searching:
**http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreate is always called when your activity is created, it doesn't matter what triggered the activity being displayed. In the official documentation regarding activity lifecycle there is no exception on this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html